# I can't find a PFET protected against ESD

Tags: mosfet, esd

I like to use [OmniFETs](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/VNP10N06-E/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu0dYp3dYbBlUps1mx%252bPR3J) for MOSFETs because they have internal protection against ESD so I am unlikely to damage them while handling and then when they don't work I don't have to wonder if it was damaged or I have a circuit mistake.  These are n-channel FETs, but now I need a p-channel FET.  I tried to find one Mouser and Digikey, but was unsuccessful.  Is there such a thing?

It would basically be a MOSFET and a diode in one package.  Other things like over-current and over-temperature protection would also be nice, but are less important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overvoltage clamp is not an ESD protection, it is a protection against an overly high input voltage during use, preventing the transistor from being turned on if too high a voltage is being applied.

The clamp will change the transistor from being switched on to being switched off electronically in case it detects overvoltage. It does not remove the voltage, only prevent a current from flowing. Sufficient ESD will still destroy the transistor.

The whole protection part can only be constructed for n-channel FETs, and not for p-channel FETs for technical reasons:

The protection circuits have to be powered. We need protection only when conductive, because that is when heat is created inside the transistor. When conductive, the source-drain voltage probably is quite low. So the only way to draw power is from gate.

Now a pfet has no voltage on gate when conductive, meaning an active protection cannot be powered.

Also, in amplifiers, where pfets are often used, it is a bad idea to use individually protected transistors. The protection circuits are not very precise, meaning the individual transistors will not turn off at the same time. Turning off only one transistor of a symmetric setup can lead to very bad results.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the device you are looking for is known as a "intelligent high-side switch"
[(a)](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM142/CL1499), [(b)](http://www.irf.com/product-info/ips/) or a "smart high-side switch".
Such as the following (which all mention electrostatic discharge protection in their datasheets):

- the [STM VN540-E](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/VN540-E/?qs=/ha2pyFadug9mqfzq/CQceH6OHiJscr/88Itw/6bBT4=)
- the [INF BTS50080-1TMA](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/BTS50080-1TMA/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuCmTIBzycWfNaB4tqdZgjBaoRCADcF3Ws=)
- the [INF BTS50080-1TMB](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/BTS50080-1TMB/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuCmTIBzycWfNaB4tqdZgjB9tl3gc5MMCU=)
- the [INF BTS50085-1TMB](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/BTS50085-1TMB/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuCmTIBzycWfNaB4tqdZgjBtYwjfPtQ/KI=)
- the [IRF AUIPS7081](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/International-Rectifier/AUIPS7081/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuCmTIBzycWfCB//05Y5UobeEvbtH5VnM0=)
- the IRF IPS521
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that it seems to me like a very futile effort to only use ESD-protected FETs. If you have a FET that is large enough to hold in your hand, it is already fairly rugged by virtue of physics. Gate and drain-source capacitance make sure that whatever charge you can inject into the device will not cause large enough voltages to spark over.

But much more importantly: when handling any other active device, you are probably holding tens, hundreds, thousands of tiny little FETs in your hand, each and every one of them orders of magnitude more sensitive to ESD. There is usually *some* protection on the outgoing pins, but I'm afraid that the only way to really set yourself free from the worry of ESD is to regard proper ESD safety:

- Regard air humidity at all times, try to keep it high (70%+). Air humidity dissipates static charges extremely effectively.
- When dealing with sensitive devices - something that is almost always mentioned in the datasheet or on the package if this is especially so - wear an ESD dissipative wrist band connected to an ESD mat, which in turn is connected to your mains electricity ground with an appropriate connector. ESD mats nowadays are very inexpensive.
- Regard your clothing. Do not wear clothing with long exposed fibers (e.g. wool).

This way  you will be able to enjoy electronics with access to the full gamut of devices, instead of having to artificially limit yourself to only those which explicitly advertise ESD protection. Which doesn't guarantee you in any way that you do avoid ESD damage either!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already 11 years old, but it the answersalready provided are either misunderstood or technically wrong.

ESD protected P-channel mosfets do in fact exist!

Here is a list of N- and P-channel devices that I recently made.
As you can see from the symbols provided, all devices on this list have ESD protection between Gate and Source pins except for the BSS123N.

[image]

Comment: SC-70 is equivalent to SOT-323, not SOT-523 as you claim in your image. SOT-523 is a smaller package than SC-70, and I don't think it has an SC number.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now